# What is the best practice way for handling model binding/validation (JSON.NET) errors?

Tags: asp.net-core

If we have a model with non-nullable properties like:

```
public class MyModel {
   public string Name {get;set;}
[MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "DisplayName should be at least 7 chars long")]
   public string DisplayName {get; set;]
   public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

and if we submit this json to it:

```
{
  "name":"Bob",
  "displayName":"MyNameIsBob"
}
```

we will get ugly error messages coming from JSON.NET serializer exceptions.

Now, I do have in place filter that handles validation and puts all the error messages (coming from DataAnnotations) into a response.

but if the json.net fails to deserialize - an exception is thrown before and very unfriendly messages end up in the model state.

one way to mitigate this is to make all non-nullable properties nullable with [Required] attribute (for those really required). That covers some cases but I believe there are a plethora of cases that even nullables could still cause json.net exception.

Is there some consistent, best practice way to handle these?

**===UPDATE===**

what i meant saying is if anything except:

1. age not included in json payload
2. age being valid integer

is included for age - it will throw exception with message like: "Could not convert {whatever wrong} to integer: {whatever}."

so, for example, if you send null or "1" for age, it will throw that error.

now, i know its a 2 step process of first formatter deserializing (and throwing these exceptions) and then binder taking over and dataannotations error messages coming into play.

i'm just wondering how to most elegently combine those two and avoding those rather ugly messages.

hope that clarified

Comment: It's not clear what your actual issue is? There is no problem deserializing here. You only have one non-nullable property, `Age` (`string` is nullable by default),  but if that's not included in the JSON, it will simply be set to the default of `0`. No error should be thrown.

Comment: @ChrisPratt There's a missing comma between the JSON properties. That would cause a deserialization error. I think they're trying to figure out how to handle that deserialization error.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i'm sorry, i probably wasn't precise enough. Please take a look at my updated question. thanks!